# All Contacts are not showing while retrieving contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I implemented a code to retrieve all contacts but it is not showing all contacts where few of them are missed.
Here is my code:

```
 String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER,
        };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, null);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();
                int indexOfNormalizedNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER);
                int indexOfDisplayName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int indexOfDisplayNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String normalizedNumber = cursor.getString(indexOfNormalizedNumber);
                    if (normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(normalizedNumber)) {
                        String displayName = cursor.getString(indexOfDisplayName);
                        String displayNumber = cursor.getString(indexOfDisplayNumber);

                        listOfContacts.add(new PhoneContactsModel(displayName, displayNumber, false));

                    } else {
                    }
                }
                Log.d("tag", "size of listOfContacts =1====" + listOfContacts.size());


            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
```

don't know what is happening. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues in the code:

1. You're querying over the `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` table, so naturally, you won't get contacts that have no phone numbers (e.g. contacts with name and email)
2. You're skipping contacts that contains phones you've already encountered in `normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound`, so if you have two contacts with a shared phone (like a home phone number) you might skip one of them.
3. `CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER` [may be null](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#NORMALIZED_NUMBER), in which case you'll skip many contacts that do not have their `NORMALIZED_NUMBER` field set

If you need to also include contacts that have no phones, I would recommend a completely different code. If you only need to get contacts with phones, I would recommend not relying on `NORMALIZED_NUMBER`, and instead add `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID` to your projection, and have that as your unique key per contact.